Easiest way to set and persist routes with a startup script?
I have a server that is ephemeral.
GCP starts the server as part of an instance template. The base image has no configuration but a handful of default Ubuntu utilities. It is multi homed (two network interfaces).
The server automatically runs a bash script.
This bash script calls a few iptables commands and adds a couple routes.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 169.252.57.134/31 -j SNAT --to $NAT
route add -net 10.0.0.0/8 gw 172.19.0.1

The server also runs unattended upgrades. The following packages were recently upgraded:
INFO Packages that will be upgraded: base-files curl initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core libc-bin libc6 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libnss-myhostname libnvme1 libpam-systemd libssl3 libsystemd-shared libsystemd0 libudev1 linux-image-cloud-amd64 openssl shim-helpers-amd64-signed shim-signed shim-signed-common shim-unsigned systemd systemd-resolved systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd udev

After the update was applied the system cleared the route statements. I don't know which package above was the culprit - but one of them must have restarted some system that cleared our routes.
The configuration for persistent routes is a yaml file or something and I don't really want to update that with a startup script. The system may restart on its own or when I update the NATs, I'll send a reboot to the server. If I were to update the config file, then I'd need to first check if the route was already there, then update the yaml, then apply the yaml.
I'd rather if I could do a route add ... followed by a route save .... Is there a way to do this?
Since it's a startup script we'd want the routes to only persist while the system is running or some easy way to make sure the startup script doesn't keep adding the same routes to the persistent configuration.

How to add static route with netplan on Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish Linux ?

My question is how do I do this without messing with Yaml.
Alternatively how do I prevent unattended upgrades from dumping ephemeral routes.
Or how do I force reboot after unattended upgrades. @cyrus
